# constexpr member function of non constexpr constructible class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

If a non-[literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) class type has no `constexpr` constructor (it is not `constexpr` constructible), does a non-static `constexpr` member function make any sense? I mean if you cannot construct the object at compile time, how would you able to use its member functions?

Anyway, the major compilers don't complain about it, which makes me think it is allowed by the standard.

Nevertheless, you are able to use such `constexpr` member functions in runtime without any problem. The only question now what is the effect of `constexpr` in this case, if any. **My best guess is that the return value of the `constexpr` member is being evaluated at compile-time (if possible), so on a run-time call it have to do a simple copy.**

Is my guess correct, or is the `constexpr` specifier absolutely meaningless in this case (i.e. the member function is being evaluated at runtime)?

Comment: I don't know much about `constexpr`, but your premise and guess both sound reasonable to me.

Comment: You may want to reword your question to focus on non-literal class types. Aggregates, for instance, don't have `constexpr` constructors but it would make sense for those to have `constexpr` member functions.

Comment: In the same way, if you provide only private constructors (without any kind of factory), You won't be able to use non-static public methods.

Comment: @Jarod42 You are able to use such `constexpr` defined functions in runtime, but it's not clear what is the expected effect of `constexpr` in this case, if any.

Comment: If a member function does not depend on state in the instance then the constancy of the instance is irrelevant. I can't think of a practical reason to support that, but maybe the standard's language would be more complex if it were to be forbidden.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The constancy and `constexpr` are independent now, since the `constexpr` specifier doesn't imply `const`

Comment: You can read that as "compile time constancy". Context. U now.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So you think that if the `constexpr` member fn doesn't depend on the state of its object (which means it could be `static`, but it isn't), it behaves like a regular non-member `constexpr` function and my guess is correct.

Comment: Your bold text is still true if you take out the word `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question seems to be that only `constexpr` functions can be evaluated at compile-time.

This premise is incorrect.  The compiler can precompute anything it can figure out a way to do, as long as the exact side result and side-effects are produced (as-if rule).

What `constexpr` provides is a guarantee that certain expressions will be evaluated at compile-time by *every* compiler (it's not a "quality of implementation" issue), which makes it possible to use them in contexts where a compile-time value is needed, such as non-type template arguments, operands of `case` clauses in `switch` statements, etc.

The specific details around `constexpr` functions include that there has to be at least one set of arguments (the target instance is an implied argument) such that the `constexpr` evaluation rules are met.  If that isn't true, your program is ill-formed and its runtime behavior is not specified at all, so don't go adding `constexpr` where it doesn't logically belong.

However, compilers aren't required to diagnose violations of this rule.  That means that "major compilers don't complain about it" should not be in any way interpreted as assurance that the code is correct.

---

Standard's wording, section 7.1.5 (draft n4582)

> For a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of
>   a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: My question didn't assume that only `constexpr` functions can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Does this mean that `template <typename T> struct A { constexpr T val() { return T(0); } };` and `template <typename T> struct A { static constexpr T val() { return T(0); } };` are (1st without, 2nd with `static`) also ill-formed? I had no problems with such functions yet.

Comment: @plasmacel: Those are fine for two reasons: (1) template functions are exempted from the rule, (2) there are no operations executed during the evaluation of those functions that are disallowed during `constexpr` processing.

Comment: @plasmacel: Here's a better example: `struct S { int i; S(j) : i{j} {} constexpr int foo() { return i; } constexpr int bar(int k) { return k? i: 0; } };` in which `foo` is ill-formed but `bar` is legal, since `o.bar(0);` won't reach any forbidden operations.

Comment: @plasmacel: Also, the two types in your comment are literal types, so they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: You are right, I wanted to define `A` non-literal type. Regarding your example, if I understand well, if a `constexpr` member function doesn't depend on any non-constexpr member variable (no matter it is template or not), that is `struct S { int i; S(j) : i{j} {} constexpr int foo() { return 1; }` then that is well-formed no matter if its object is `constexpr` or not. In other words it is obviously ill-formed only when it tries to access a non-constexpr member.